# Rails: How to save attribute for parent User (current_user) when submitting form to create child object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model (using Devise) and a Listing model. User has_many :listings and Listing belongs_to :user.

The user has email, password and phone number attributes, but when creating an account, only email and password are required. Phone number can be left blank.

When a logged-in user creates a Listing, I'd like to provide the option for the current user to include his phone number using the same form. The expectation is to store the phone number of the user who is creating the listing.

I've created forms to accept nested attributes for child objects before, but not for parent object like this case. I haven't figured out how to get the form to do this, and whether I need to change something in the controller or models. Any help is appreaciated.

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Listing model

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Listings controller

```
  def create
    @listing = current_user.listings.build(listing_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to listing_url(@listing), notice: "Listing was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        ...
      end
    end
  end
```

New Listing Form

```
<%= form_with model: @listing do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :title, class: "label required" %>
    <div class="control"> 
      <%= f.text_field :title, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "title", required: true, class: "input" %>
    </div>
  </div>


...


<% end>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For save the phone at the user, you can do something like that in the controller:

```
def create
    @listing = current_user.listings.build(listing_params)

    user = current_user
    user.phone = params[:phone]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save && user.save
        format.html { redirect_to listing_url(@listing), notice: "Listing was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        ...
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hi @Matteo, I tried this but I am getting the following error: 
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError at /listings unknown attribute 'phone' for Listing.

Because phone really is an attribute of the User and not the Listing.
Any way to work around this?

Comment: How have you make the .erb file? If the params is like
params[:listing][:phone], i think in the line
@listing = current_user.listings.build(listing_params)
trying to insert phone in listing, and it is wrong. It dipend by the Front end. In this case, sometimes i create a simpre input field without simple_form, like: <input type="number" name="phone">. In this case, you have the phone separe from listing params and the code on up should work

Comment: I've just added the form section of the .erb file.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a little overcomplicated, but it uses the standard nested attributes and strong params. It will also prepopulate the phone input if the data is available.

Enable nested_attributes on `Listing.user`. Limit it to `update_only` since you don't want to be able to create a user in this way.

```rb
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, update_only: true
end
```

Add the following nested form to the Listing form partial. Note that `include_id` is set to false so that the User's ID is not exposed in the form.

```rb
  <%= f.fields_for :user, include_id: false do |uf| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= uf.label :phone, class: "label required" %>
      <div class="control">
        <%= uf.text_field :phone, autofocus: true, 
        autocomplete: "title", required: true, class: "input" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Permit the nested user params in the controller:

```rb
  def listing_params
    params.fetch(:listing, {}).permit(:title, user_attributes: [:phone])
  end
```

Initialize the Listing with a user in the `new` action of the controller.

```rb
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new(user: @current_user)
  end
```

Finally, in your `create` action, you'll need to merge the user id into the params, since it wasn't included with the form submission. The user id has to be set both in the nested attributes, and on the new listing record.

```rb
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(
      listing_params.to_h.deep_merge(
        user_id: @current_user.id,
        user_attributes: { id: @current_user.id }
      ))

    ...

  end
```

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for your answer. It all makes sense but I found one problem: the fields_for form is not showing up. Is there anything missing in the controller maybe?

Comment: @FelipeCerda did you initialize the Listing with the current user in def new ? My `fields_for` form didn't show up until I did that. Also requires that @current_user is actually present.

Comment: I did, just like you suggested. What do you mean with "@current_user is actually present?"

Comment: @current_user can't be nil, but I assume that's not a problem since you're using devise. Not sure what else would prevent the sub form from rendering

Comment: I managed to make the field appear by adding current_user to fields_for like so: <%= f.fields_for :user, current_user, include_id: false do |uf| %> but it's not actually updating the user with the phone number. No errors shown either. Any suggestions?

Comment: that would require some debugging: you'll need to see what data is being sent to the POST create route either through the browser's network log or by looking at the rails development log.